# RSP overwrite but not RIP

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, buffer-overflow

While following along with this [video on buffer overflows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sUd3AA7Q50) I was seeing a different result in my initial overrun.

Steps:

- install gdb-peda
- create exploitable -- insecure.c
- create pattern to overrun buffer -- pattern.txt
- run "r < pattern.txt" in gdb
- figure out buffer for RIP inject point
- create input for exploitable using python -- see code below
- run "r < offset.txt"

In the example the narrators rip register contains a pattern, however here is what is in mine:

```
RIP: 0x401201 (<secure+104>:    ret)
```

my RSP however does contain a segment of the pattern:

```
RSP: 0x7fffffffdf48 ("nA%CA%-A%(A%DA%;A%)A%EA%aA%0A%FA%bA%1A%GA%cA%2A%HA%dA%3A%IA%eA%4A%JA%fA%5A%KA%gA%6A%LA%hA%7A%MA%iA%8A%NA%jA%9A%OA%kA%PA%lA%QA%mA%RA%oA%SA%pA%TA%qA%UA%rA%VA%tA%WA%uA%XA%vA%YA%wA%ZA%xA%y")
```

the offset for the RSP pattern is 16

Despite this I continued to follow along and used the overflow byte count the narrator did:
216 + 'BBBB'

Result?

```
RIP: 0xa42424242 ('BBBB\n')
```

I just want to know why I didn't initially see a pattern in RIP when using a 400 count buffer?

```
//insecure.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int hackme(){
    system("touch hacked.txt && ls -la");
    return 0;
}
int secure(){
    char buffer[200];
    int input;

    input = read(0,buffer,400);
    printf("\n[+] user supplied: %d-bytes!", input);
    printf("\n[+] buffer content --> %s!", buffer);

    return 0;

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    return secure();
}
```

```
command used to compile
gcc insecure.c -g -o vulnerable -fno-stack-protector -W -z execstack -no-pie
```

```
pattern code
pattern create 216 pattern.txt
```

```
python code for overrun
python3 -c 'print("A" * 216 + "BBBB")' > offset.txt
```

OS Info:

- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Arch: x86_64